# how to test my microservice (dropwizard) SSL configuration if it is successfully being setup?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, yaml, dropwizard, microservices

here's my yml configuration:

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
    - type: https
      port: 8443
      keyStorePath: xxxx.keystore
      keyStorePassword: xxxx
      validateCerts: false
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
    - type: https
      port: 8444
      keyStorePath: xxxx.keystore
      keyStorePassword: xxxx
      validateCerts: false
```

and in the logs:
it has a

```
GET     /file/hello (com.xxx.xxxx.resource.MultiPartResource)

Started application@48f5bde6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Started application@525d79f0{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
```

full lines:

```
INFO  [2016-02-23 02:25:15,996] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started application@48f5bde6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO  [2016-02-23 02:25:16,011] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started application@525d79f0{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
```

and in the postman:
i invoke this url

```
https://localhost:8443/file/hello
```

and i get a response of

[image]

how to determine if my configuration of yml is correct for SSL?

Comment: Note that Postman doesn't have SSL verification interface; it uses Chrome's own. So the first time that certificate is presented, what you need to do is click on the link (https:// localhost....), accept the certificate and then resend your request. Then it should start functioning.

Comment: ahm... if so how to determine the Multipart? because i cannot do a multipart upload if not using a postman?

Comment: @Natan do you have an idea how to test a SSL Multipart?

Comment: @suwangging try this, quit all chrome windows and reopen chrome in insecure mode. Then open postman and try invoking the https url. Becareful not to open any other external urls when chrome is in insecure mode.